# How do I change where in the SVN repository my project gets saved (KEEP IT EASY TO UNDERSTAND)

Tags: svn, repository, subversive, trunk, svn-trunk

How do I change where in the SVN repository my project gets saved?

At the moment, my project is supposed to save in ProjectName111, but is instead saving in trunk/Project112. How do I change it to save to ProjectName111? I need fast help. Thanks

Also, I need the answer to be easy enough for a high schooler to understand, ok?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking.  If you're trying to move or rename something in the repository, you can do that with the [move](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) command:

```
svn move http://your_repository/oldname http://your_repository/newname
```